# Why could the dragon not bring back Goku after he fought Frieza?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

After Goku fought Frieza and the planet blew up, everybody on earth thought Goku was dead. So they used the dragon balls to wish to bring Goku back to life, but the dragon then told them that Goku was still alive. They then asked the dragon to teleport Goku back to Earth. The dragon then said no, because Goku did not want to.

So why would the dragon listen to Goku, who was not making the wish?

Comment: Maybe because their original wish was to bring him back alive. Since Goku wasn't dead, their wish won't have any effects at all. But since they changed their wish, your question is still valid. Or maybe you can't change your original wish? Just guessing.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Goku sayd to Porunga, that he doesn't want to return to earth. When I have time, I'll watch it again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Porunga is not able to relocate someone against their will as stated in the [Porunga Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Porunga). Its his limitation. As Shenron has his own limitation like granting only one wish, not able to resurrect the same person more then one time. Porunga has his own limitation of not relocating someone without his own will.

Comment: But if I remembered correctly Gohan did not want to leave his dad. but he still was transported back to earth. I can be wrong, has been a while since I watched dbz

Comment: @user1526 didn't remember which episode you are referring , give me a little time to dig a bit more.

Comment: I am referring to the episode where everybody is wished back to earth except for Goku and freeza. if I am right Gohan did not want to leave his daddy, but still got teleported to earth(against his will).

Comment: @user1526 i think he never said no to porunga directly and he agreed later.

Comment: If I have the time ill watch it again, but for now I am satisfied :D

Comment: So Vegeta really wanted to leave Namek?

Comment: @IG_42 Probably.  It was about to explode and he did seem pretty convinced that Freiza and Goku were both well beyond his current power.  Of course, my interpretation of the scene in this answer is that "those of sufficient (will)power can prevent the relocation", and only Goku had the requisite amount of (will)power at that time.  Dendee's dragon was based upon Shenron, including Shenron's limitations, and Shenron was already known to be unable to forcibly relocate or kill those stronger than itself (it couldn't get rid of Nappa and Vegeta originally).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about this, but I have two theories.

1. Goku is much stronger than Shenron and Shenron was simply too weak to teleport Goku against his will.
2. Shenron is generally not able to grant wishes which are against one specific will.

    
   [Here](http://www.pojo.biz/board/archive/index.php/t-715728.html) is another discussion about this topic. I did not read everything so I don't know if they got a real answer.

Sorry that I don't comment your question, but I don't have enought reputation. So I "answered".

Comment: Shenron was the dragon from kami right?but the wishes where made on Dendee's dragon. don't know if it would add anything

Comment: Thats right. But I still think Goju was stronger as super sayan ;).

Comment: @j0chn he is Porunga  not Shenron. Because Shenron doesnot exists after fusion of Picolo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because Goku/Kakarot was going to come back in due time anyways. So the dragon let it slip by like when the dragon had to check if he could make a certain wish. Maybe the dragon only does stuff that can't already happen naturally.

Comment: An early wish in Dragonball came from Oolong, and he simply wished for a pair of girls underwear.  Even though we might reasonably believe Oolong couldn't convince a girl to give these to him, he could simply go out and buy them at a store.  So that easily happens naturally, yet still gets granted.